# How to access locator that is created in App.xaml from the code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `App.xaml` the locator instance is created:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                         d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Now I would like to access `Locator` object from `ViewModel`. How can I refer to that object from the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var locator = (ViewModelLocator) Application.Current.Resources["Locator"];
```